# Django unittest : 'or' assertEqual test possible?

Tags: django, django-testing

What I want to do is,

```
self.assertEqual(Query_A, Query_B) or self.assertIn(QuerySet_C, QuerySet_D)  # pass either one pass test.
```

Is it possible in `Django`?

What I did:

```
self.assertTrue(
    self.assertEqual(
        Query_A,
        Query_B
    )
    or
    self.assertIn(
        QuerySet_C,
        QuerySet_D
    )
)
```

but it doesn't work.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.assertTrue(a in b or c in d)
```

for your update:

```
self.assertTrue(Query_A == Query_B or QuerySet_C in QuerySet_D)
```

Comment: it is working for me right now...are you sure your equality/in's are evaluating like you expect them to?

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
self.assertTrue(x == y or a in b)
```

Example: http://ideone.com/RHAiSb